# How to select Event name when adding Custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I created events on my website using `gtag("event", "qualify", { site: "Example site" })` and I can see the data is being sent to GA (real time report).

Now I want to create a report showing all users that qualify (event) with the site name (event parameter). I read that I need to create a Custom dimension. Where do I select the Event name?

[image: Form to add/edit custom dimension]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you have no possibility to select the Event name. If some of your events have parameters with same names, GA will create one custom dimension. This dimension will displays in reports of every event, which has parameter with selected name.